# Magento 2 - How can I show specific products on homepage

Tags: magento2, product, product-list

I am trying to find a way to show specific products (that I will select from the admin area) in Homepage. I see there is a widget for products from a specific category but there is none for selecting products and showing them. I thought about creating a widget but I am not sure on how to show the products on the admin area. Could you please help me show specific products on homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below content in your CMS home page block (Content -> Block)

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_per_page="8" products_count="8" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`sku`,`operator`:`()`,`value`:`WS12, WT09, MT07, MH07, 24-MB02, 24-WB04, 241-MB08, 240-LV05`^]^]"}}
```

Change the sku as per your need.

**Reference** : `Content -> Block -> Home Page Block`

Comment: While this is a good solution I am building this website for a client. I need him to choose the products dynamically without writing any code.